# I want my graph to have more points and also to be able to move each point independently of each other

Tags: python, matplotlib

I'm only getting one of the points to move with the cursor, I want all the other points I want to place to also move.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as patches

# cria os pontos iniciais
x = [0, 1]
y = [0, 30]


fig1 = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig1.add_subplot(111, aspect='equal')

# cria o gráfico de setor
wedge = ax1.add_patch(
    patches.Wedge(
        (0, 0),         # (x,y)
        100,            # radius
        120,             # theta1 (in degrees)
        180,            # theta2
        color="g", alpha=0.2
    )
)

# cria o gráfico de dispersão
scatter = ax1.scatter(x, y)

# define a função de atualização que é chamada quando os pontos são movidos
def on_move(event):
    if not event.inaxes:
        return
    if event.button != 1:
        return
    x, y = event.xdata, event.ydata
    index = scatter.get_paths()[0].contains_point((x, y))
    if index == 0:
        scatter.set_offsets([(x, y), scatter.get_offsets()[1]])
    elif index == 1:
        scatter.set_offsets([scatter.get_offsets()[0], (x, y)])
    wedge_center = (x, y)
    wedge.set_center(wedge_center)
    fig1.canvas.draw()

# conecta a função de atualização ao evento de movimentação dos pontos
cid = fig1.canvas.mpl_connect('motion_notify_event', on_move)

plt.axis([-150, 150, 0, 250])

plt.show()
```

I hope you can add as many points as you want and that everyone can move around.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.